# Why does Android org.json.* not implement the Map interface?

Tags: android, json, interface, dictionary

It seems so strange that Android org.json.* does not implement the Map interface:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Anybody know why?  Have an idea of a simple way to get round this, or are we stuck with a specific separate way of navigating a series of nested Maps when we happen to be using JSON?

Many thanks in advance
CHEERS> SAM

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well I found a way to get an arbitrarily nested List/Map object back through a conversion process.  Probably awfully inefficient as it relies on multiple JSONExceptions, but does what I need:

```
private static Map<String, Object> jsonObjectToMap(JSONObject object) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Iterator<String> keys = object.keys();
    String key;
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        key = keys.next();
        try {
            map.put(key, jsonObjectToMap(object.getJSONObject(key)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            try {
                map.put(key, jsonArrayToList(object.getJSONArray(key)));
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                try {
                    map.put(key, object.getString(key));
                } catch (JSONException e2) {
                    try {
                        map.put(key, object.getInt(key));
                    } catch (JSONException e3) {
                        try {
                            map.put(key, object.getLong(key));
                        } catch (JSONException e4) {
                            try {
                                map.put(key, object.getBoolean(key));
                            } catch (JSONException e5) {
                                try {
                                    map.put(key, object.getDouble(key));
                                } catch (JSONException e6) {
                                    try {
                                        map.put(key, object.get(key));
                                    } catch (JSONException e7) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e7.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

    return map;
}

private static List<Object> jsonArrayToList(JSONArray array) {
    List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        try {
            arrayList.add(jsonObjectToMap(array.getJSONObject(i)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            try {
                arrayList.add(jsonArrayToList(array.getJSONArray(i)));
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                try {
                    arrayList.add(array.getString(i));
                } catch (JSONException e2) {
                    try {
                        arrayList.add(array.getInt(i));
                    } catch (JSONException e3) {
                        try {
                            arrayList.add(array.getLong(i));
                        } catch (JSONException e4) {
                            try {
                                arrayList.add(array.getBoolean(i));
                            } catch (JSONException e5) {
                                try {
                                    arrayList.add(array.getDouble(i));
                                } catch (JSONException e6) {
                                    try {
                                        arrayList.add(array.get(i));
                                    } catch (JSONException e7) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e7.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Would be great if support for this could be built in to json.org as an alternative way of returning the data, rather than having to do an expensive conversion.

Comment: Are you kidding me!? That's garbage!

Comment: everything is true from some point of view - it's served it's purpose for me at the time

Answer (score 5):

I'd also love to know why Android's JSON library doesn't implement the standard interfaces... but regardless, here's one way to convert the types yourself:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.*;

public class JsonHelper {
    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
        Iterator keys = object.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            map.put(key, fromJson(object.get(key)));
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static List toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            list.add(fromJson(array.get(i)));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static Object fromJson(Object json) throws JSONException {
        if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
            return toMap((JSONObject) json);
        } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
            return toList((JSONArray) json);
        } else {
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you could extend it and implement that interface if you desired. As to why, I suspect it has to do with holding heterogeneous data in a type safe way without have to do a bunch of ugly casts.

*[update] Also this object works a lot with primitives which don't work so well with generic map interface.*

Comment: extending it looks painful.  I just wrote a jsonToMap converter but it won't be very efficient due to all the exception throwing.  Personally I think type safety is highly over-rated.  In the first instance I just want to get at the data as a nested set of Map and lists referring to Strings ... it is so intensely irritating that maybe I will try to extend, but json is so simple it is difficult to believe there is not a simple raw jsonToMap converter out there ...

Comment: "I think type safety is highly over-rated" - you, my friend, are going to hate Java :)

Comment: I've been hating that aspect of Java for about 5 years, mainly since I started programming in Ruby/JavaScript etc.  The 10 years of Java before that was "Okay", but I had no idea what I was missing :-)